# Yup-Password validation

Tags: validation, passwords, yup

Has anybody used the new yup-password validation? I have tried it and failed. I referred the documentation but couldn't make sense of it. Can anybody please help? [Link to the yup-password documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-password)

Answer (score 1):

[yup-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup-password) is a [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) plugin so you would first need to have `yup` installed.

Run the following to install both `yup` and `yup-password`:

```sh
$ npm install yup yup-password
```

Then include both packages in your project as shown in the documentation and
type out your schema.

```js
// 1. import `yup`
const yup = require('yup')
// 2. setup `yup-password`
// this line extends yup's StringSchema with the
// methods shown in yup-password's documentation
require('yup-password')(yup)

// 3. build your validation schema
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    username: yup.string().email().required(),
    password: yup.string().password().required(),
})

// The user input
const input = {
    username: 'user@example.com',
    // since the following password does not meet the
    // default criteria, it will fail validation.
    password: 'my password',
}

// 4. run the validation
// using async/await
void (async () => {
    try {
        // the `{ abortEarly: false }` is optional, but I'm adding there
        // so that we can see all the failed password conditions.
        const res = await schema.validate(input, { abortEarly: false })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.errors) // => [
        //   'password must be at least 8 characters',
        //   'password must contain at least 1 upper-cased letter',
        //   'password must contain at least 1 number',
        //   'password must contain at least 1 symbol',
        // ]
    }
})()
// using promises
schema
    .validate(input, { abortEarly: false })
    .then(() => console.log('success!'))
    .catch(e => console.log('validation failed: ' + e.errors.join(', ')))
```

In case you are not satisfied with the default password criteria, you can use the rest of the added methods to customize the behavior to your liking.
For example:

```js
const schema = yup
    .string()
    // at least 3 lowercase characters
    .minLowercase(3)
    // at least 2 uppercase characters
    .minUppercase(2)
    // and at least 6 numbers
    .minNumber(6)

schema
    .validate('my password')
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch(e => console.log('failed: ' + e.errors.join(', ')))
```

I hope this clears things up a bit.